# Dedicated settings for Azure web jobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a bunch of azure `Web jobs` on one `App Service` hosted on one `App Service plan`.

Each web jobs have their own role & function & **settings**.

[image]

Settings can only be defined (or overridden) at `App Service` level.

Does it mean

- I missed the concept & granularity of `web jobs` ?
- I should add some kind of prefix in my settings ?

Comment: Settings can be defined in the app.config file and then be overidden from the Azure Portal. So dont set you settings from the portal and only stick to app.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'settings' you are referring to Azure Web App settings, then indeed they are shared among all WebJobs within an App Service.

If you need them to be different, you can simply host each WebJob in a different Web App. Both Web Apps can be in the same App Service Plan, so this won't cost you anything more.

Comment: I prefer to reduce the number of entity we have to monitor. is there any drawbacks of using a single web app for several web jobs ?

Comment: @camous there is no real drawback if you can deal with the limitation that they share all app settings.

Comment: one drawback I've found (but acceptable in my situation), as soon as one file is edited on the webapp, azure detects it and all webjobs are restarted.

Comment: That should not normally be the case. Editing a file in the web app (e.g. under wwwroot) should not cause the WebJobs to restart.

Comment: I think yes :) "[09/16/2016 12:55:37 > d799ad: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob"

Comment: We probably need a new question to properly investigate, as this is really a different topic. Make sure you specify exactly what file you are changing.